# iptables: allow OUTPUT only for http and ssh

Tags: linux, http, ssh, iptables

How to allow outgoing trafic only for http and ssh?

i've tried:

```
 iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT
```

but as soon as i add

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

nothing works, it blocks everything.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:22151
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:sso-service
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `--sport` instead of `--dport`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the output of your iptables configuration does not matches the rules you  have typed. Did you restarted iptable service? Second, you will need to allow udp on port 53 to get DNS working as well:

```
 iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```